# Can one table have an exclusive lock while updating a second table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2016. I have two tables, one is a queue of work items (`TQueue`), and the second is the work items (`TWork`) that are being processed.

I have a script that grabs the top 100 items from `TQueue` that do not have a record in `TWork`, and then inserts those items into `TWork` to be processed.

For performance reasons, I want to run multiple instances of the script simultaneously. The challenge is that Script 1 grabs 100 items, and before the transaction to insert these items into `TWork` is committed, Script 2 grabs the same set of items and inserts them as well.

**Question**

I would like to block the reading of `TQueue` until insert transaction into `TWork` has completed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use table hints to achieve this goal.

For example:

```
Create Table Val (ID Int)

Insert Into Val (ID)
Values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

First session:

```
Set Transaction Isolation level Read Committed

Begin Transaction

Select Top 2 * From Val With (ReadPast, XLock, RowLock)
-- Return 0,1

-- Commit has been commented for illustrative purposes.
-- Don't forget to commit the transaction later.

-- Commit
```

Second session:

```
Set Transaction Isolation level Read Committed

Begin Transaction

Select * From Val With (ReadPast, XLock, RowLock)
-- Return 2,3,4,5

Commit
```